# Trying to create Total count from the group

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) Viewer_Count
    , EVENT_NAME
    SELECT SUM (COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)) AS total_view
FROM dsv1069.EVENTS
GROUP BY EVENT_NAME
```

Error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
> Position: 66
> ,EVENT_NAME
> SELECT SUM (COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)) AS total_view

Comment: Seems you want to tag PostgreSQL *not* SQL Server. Seems you are just missing a bracket (and a comma) before you sub-query select - pretty much like the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using derive table technique to get a SUM of aggregated column. You cannot use aggregation over another aggregated column or sub query. And in your query, there are syntax errors where you have defined the sub query wrong and comma is mission.  plsql, mysql, sqllite syntaxes are somewhat similar. What matters is the way we use the technique.   If you can provide your table definition and data, I can provide a better solution.

```
SELECT 
  viewer_Count
 ,EVENT_NAME
 ,SUM(total_view) AS [total-View_Sum]
FROM
  (
   SELECT
     COUNT(user_id) AS viewer_Count
     , EVENT_NAME
     , COUNT(distinct user_id)  AS total_view
  FROM  dsv1069.EVENTS
  GROUP BY  EVENT_NAME
  ) AS A
GROUP BY viewer_Count
,EVENT_NAME
```